# How do I give velocity to players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help with modifying the players velocity in Minecraft.

I have tried:

```
/data merge entity Bla0 {Motion:[0.0, 0.8, 0.0]}
```

and

```
/data modify entity Bla0 Motion[0] set value 0.001d
```

but both give the error message:

> Unable to modify player data.

I run minecraft 1.18.2 with optifine. The server is on paper with no plugins.

Comment: Um, speed potions?

Comment: @aytimothy speed potions do not give players velocity. They increase a players maximum speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is you cannot. Certain types of data are unable to be modified like that, and it is considered "[works as intended](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-122102)" by Mojang. Basically, certain types of data are static, so to alter them would require the player to rejoin the world. Their solution was to just make them unable to be modified.

You can read more about it here: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-122102